# Add field from rendered entity in view

Tags: views, entities

I would like to display the body summary of a single, specific article in the header of a view using the "entity: rendered entity" option and selecting "content." I can display the full content of the article and the teaser, but I don't see a way to access the article's fields individually. I don't want to display the title / author information. (My (probably wrong) guess is the "tokens" option, but upon selecting it, I see no place to utilize the tokens.) Insight appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you can display the Full & Teaser view modes, then you can display any custom view modes, too.

Install the [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) module and create a new 'view mode' - let's call it "body" - and on the same screen, make sure it's applied to nodes. Then go to Structure -> Content Types -> Article (or whatever your content type is called) -> Manage Display, and you will see three tabs: Default, Teaser and Body (the view mode you just created). Scroll to the bottom of the page and choose a layout (single column should do the trick), and then drag the body field into the appropriate region. Don't forget to save the form after rearranging fields.

At this point you can go into your view, and select the new 'Body' view mode where the options for 'Full' and 'Teaser' were showing up earlier.